# Django: How do I setup SNS with boto3?

Tags: django, amazon-sns, boto3

I am trying to get the `SNS` service with [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3) going for my application.
I got as far as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268177/django-boto3-nocredentialserror-unable-to-locate-credentials), but how do I actually setup an `SNS` service specifically (not `S3`)?
What I need to know is how to connect and catch any exceptions while doing so.

**Solution:**

in my `settings.py` I added these lines:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "..."
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "..."
AWS_REGION = "eu-central-1"
```

and where I use the SNS service I did it like this:

```
sns = boto3.client(service_name="sns",
            aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            region_name=settings.AWS_REGION, use_ssl=True)

topics = self.sns.list_topics()
```

Comment: The `boto3` way should be `sns = boto3.resource('sns')` and `topics = list(sns.topics.all())` if you are looking for a list of [`Topic`](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#topic) resources. Exceptions are not documented, but from my experience are instances of `botocore.exceptions.BotoCoreError` subclasses. Please be a little more explicit on the difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Thanks. Why should I use `resource` instead of `client`?

Comment: A resource is a bit simpler to use since it is on a resource-based model. So you can say `s3.Bucket('bucket').Object('key')` instead of `s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket', Key='key')`. Performance wise, the difference is negligible. You will sometimes find, however, that a `resource` does not contain all of the service methods. This is because, more often than not, the `resource` is an abstraction over a service that is not actually resource-based.

Also, please please please do not hard code credentials. If you're running django from an EC2 instance, you can give the instance an IAM role instead.

Comment: Let me add that when a resource lacks the method you are looking for, you can always access it's `meta` attribute, which is a pointer to the low-level machinery. So you can e.g. `topic.meta.client.get_endpoint_attributes('endpoint-arn')`